# Spring Initializr (Spring boot) does not create the WEB-INF in its archtype

Tags: java, spring

I went to site of start.spring.io and selected the Web Service option with SOAP, but when I downloaded and added the .zip in Spring Tool Suite IDE, it generated an archtype automatically that does not have the WEB-INF folder or the web.xml file.

I don´t know if the Spring was designed to search these files in other place, or maybe I have to create them. If it is the case, I don´t understand why Spring boot could not generate the files automatically.

Someone knows why?

Comment: I have found the solution. It is simple. You have to select the project in the IDE and with the right button select the option "Properties of WSSpring" and In the place of Mave/Proyect Facets, toy have to activate the options Java and Dynamic Web Module.

Comment: I am not really following. There are other directories that the service does not generated by default (because they are not mandatory). What is wrong creating the directory yourself?

Comment: The solution is simple, I should have to read more about the spring boot.
Spring boot does not need an web-inf, He has its own aplication server inside. Only have to respect the code SpringApplication.run(SpringOrmApplication.class, args); and the magic is done.

Answer (score 3):

Spring initializer creates an application with embeded tomcat, which has everything configured so you dont see any web-inf folder. if you want web-inf then use following pom.xml i.e excluding tomcat will give you separate web-inf folder.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```